# maven android pom.xml

Tags: android, maven

I have set up my an in house nexus repository. Now i have changed my settings.xml file to point to my repository, but i also want to include the reference in my project pom.xml file. Now is this pom.xml file valid ? If i change the password of the repo, maven still downloads the file from the repo ? What am i doing wrong ? Is this configuration correct ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycomp</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestAndroid</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>Test Android Application</name>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>com-repo</id>
            <username>admin</username>
            <password>admin</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com-repo</id>
            <url>http://central</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>com-repo</id>
            <name>com-repo</name>
            <url>http://10.10.10.230:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-android-rest-template</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>20030203.000129</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
            <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.google</groupId>
            <artifactId>admob</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mycpmp</groupId>
            <artifactId>1234</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test</groupId>
            <artifactId>test</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.taptwo.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>widget</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>apklib</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>dfp-lib</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>0.4.0</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->


    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <attachSources>true</attachSources>
                    <sign>
                        <debug>false</debug>
                    </sign>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>16</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>signing</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sign</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <inherited>true</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <archiveDirectory></archiveDirectory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>target/*.apk</include>
                            </includes>
                            <keystore>avm.keystore</keystore>
                            <storepass>123</storepass>
                            <keypass>123</keypass>
                            <alias>asdfg</alias>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The credentials are only for deploying to the repository.  Repositories for deployment are defined in a [distributionManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) element; it's distinct from the repositories element stuff.  The repositories element defines repos where your dependencies are resolved from.

Moreover, the pom doesn't support putting the credentials in like this.  Are you getting errors when you execute it?  I would think so.

Comment: Other then this, is this pom.xml valid ?

Comment: No, i dont get an error, but i removed this. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your pom is not valid.
As stated in [here](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html), you should not put the username and password in the pom.xml.

> The repositories for download and deployment are defined by the repositories and distributionManagement elements of the POM. However, certain settings such as username and password should not be distributed along with the pom.xml. This type of information should exist on the build server in the settings.xml.